# What was "Muktaphala" according to Hinduism?

Tags: meaning, story

I was just wondering what is "Muktaphala". I think literary it means "Pearl fruit", right? But was it a single pearl or many pearls embedded in a single fruit? Can anyone explain? And is it mentioned anywhere in Hindu mythology or literature book?

Edit: I heard this term in one of the dohas, I don't remember it fully, it was either of Rahim or Kabir. It said "Muktaphal mukta chugai aru uri anat naa jahi". It means that swans were eating pearl fruit.

Comment: Hullo Arpita, Welcome to Hinduism community. Could you share where you heard  this  term  first and what was the context?. This would help us understanding the question better. Thank you.